# WPF TextBlock TextTrimming Not Working Inside a Grid With GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ellipsis

I have the following structure in my XAML code:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MinWidth="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>           
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesCollectionView}" Margin="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Foreground="Black" FontSize="14">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Foreground="Gray" FontSize="12">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <GridSplitter Width="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
<!--More stuff here......-->
```

I made the XAML code short here or it just clutter the whole question. I have 5 columns, on this order, left to right: `ListBox`, `GridSplitter`, `RichTextBox`, `GridSplitter`, `ListView`. I am just showing the first two columns since the rest is just about the same.

When I load my program the `TextBoxes` aren't showing any Ellipsis, never. I even tried giving the `ListBox` a fixed size.

**Does anyone knows how to fix Ellipsis to be shown?** I believe this might be involved on how the controls inside a `Grid` are informed about their sizes when there is a `GridSplitter`.

I am aiming for a UI where the middle view has a `* width` and the left and right ones are fixed size at first but can be stretched if the user wants to.

---

### EDIT:

## This is what I want:

[image: Text with Ellipsis]

## This is what I am getting:

[image: Text without Ellipsis]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, if you've found an solution yet, but I think the following could help you (see my comments inline):

```
<Window x:Class="SO40013780.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO40013780"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="200">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Name="TheList" Grid.Column="0">
      <ListBox.Template>
        <!-- Override the default controll template for the listbox -->
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
          <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <!-- OBS: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" is the CHANGE -->
            <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
              <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="White"/>
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </ListBox.Template>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Background="Yellow" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <GridSplitter Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Column="2" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

It has nothing to do with the colums and splitters as I thought in the first place.

The magic in the above xaml is the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" on the scroll viewer in the template. With this setting horizontal scrolling in the listbox is disabeled, and therefore the text trimming in the inline text blocks should take over when the listbox becomes narrower than the text in the items.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this would help? What is the improvement? What's the secret ingredient?

Comment: @mFeinstein: I'm really just trying to help. It must be rather easy for you to test if it works (Just copy/paste the ListBox.Template-tag into your xaml and se the result). There are two inline comments in the code above. The HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" on ScrollViewer does the trick (is the secret ingredient).

Comment: I am just trying to understand your solution and how it works and why

Comment: Ok, Now I understand your idea, yes, it works, thanks! But the only code I need is `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the `ListBox`, no need to set the whole template for this.

Comment: @mFeinstein: OK, even smarter and cleaner. Good coding from here.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Henrik Hansen's answer I realized the solution was quite simple, just a simple line of code on the `ListBox`.

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

This prevents the inner controls to acquire all the width they want, restricting them to the column's width instead.

Answer (score -1):

Ellipsis is not changed when text property is changed inside a content control. I checked ms documents. In order to do it, you should write a property and bind TextTrimProperty to it (do the logic in your viewmodel) or write a converter for your TextBlock
or 
you can write your own TextBlock class and create a callback method for textblock text property.Then manipulate your text in it.
As I told you, texttrimming is not fired after text is changed.

Comment: I am actuallly using MVVM, but thias makes no difference at the end I think. I would just change the name to `Message`, since the `Collection` implies it's a collection, which clearly it isn't. I will test this and let you know.

Comment: What exactly did you change in my code? Just to be clear, I am not getting `Ellipsis` on the text, I do get the text, just huuuge text beyond the `GridSplitter` limits, do you get `Ellipsis` when resizing the column using the `GridSplitter`?.

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? My ViewModel also shows all the correct strings in the TextBoxes.

Comment: I think you got me wrong again. It's not about changing the text. It's about getting it to work even on the first time, when there was no change. If I make the TextBlock fixed size it works, so this isn't related to binding.

Comment: @mFeinstein if you dont set textblock width to fixed size, it is meaningless to use texttrim.I dont understand , if you want to use texttrim obviously you have to make your textblock width as fixed size.

Comment: That's not obvious, I want it to automatically set ellipsis when the textblock text is clipped by the column size.